# Shared Memory - Warning: Comparison Between Pointer and Integer

Tags: c, pointers, shared-memory

I am working on a school project and everything is working, but on compiling I get the warning "Comparison between pointer and integer". Can anyone explain why this happens? I get the same warning on all four of the shared memory initializations below. I have tried different methods for making the comparison. As far as I have read, shmget and shmat should return -1 on an error. Even though the warning comes up, the code works perfectly well. I have made changes to prompt the errors. These warnings are prompting on the shmat lines. Minimal code listed below.

```
//--------------------------------------------------
//Variables
//--------------------------------------------------

//Shared memory variables
int (*clockVar)[2];
int *turn;
int (*shmMsg)[2];
enum state {idle, want_in, in_cs, done, dne} *flag;
long *pidList;

//Shared memory keys
key_t clockKey;
key_t turnKey;
key_t msgKey;
key_t flagKey;
key_t pidKey;

//Shared memory IDs
int clockID = 0;
int turnID = 0;
int msgID = 0;
int flagID = 0;
int pidID = 0;
//--------------------------------------------------
//Key Initialization
//--------------------------------------------------

clockKey = ftok("ftok_clock", 13);
if (clockKey == -1){
    perror("Clock: Failed to load ftok file");
    return 1;
}

msgKey = ftok("ftok_msg", 17);
if (msgKey == -1){
    perror("Message: Failed to load ftok file");
    return 1;
}

flagKey = ftok("ftok_flag", 15);
if (flagKey == -1){
    perror("Flag: Failed to load ftok file");
    return 1;
}

pidKey = ftok("ftok_pids", 17);
if (pidKey == -1){
    perror("PID: Failed to load ftok file");
    return 1;
}

//--------------------------------------------------
//Shared Memory Initialization
//--------------------------------------------------

//Initializing shared memory for clock counter
clockID = shmget(clockKey, sizeof(int[2][1]), IPC_CREAT | 0666);
if (clockID == -1){
    perror("Clock: Failed to designate shared memory");
    return 1;
}

clockVar = shmat(clockID, 0, 0);
if (clockVar == (int*)-1){
    perror("Clock: Failed to attach shared memory");
    return 1;
}

//Initializing shared memory for the Message array
msgID = shmget(msgKey, sizeof(int[2][1]), IPC_CREAT | 0666);
if (msgID == -1){
    perror("Message: Failed to designate shared memory");
    return 1;
}

shmMsg = shmat(msgID, NULL, 0);
if (shmMsg == (int*)-1){
    perror("Message: Failed to attach shared memory");
    return 1;
}

//Initializing shared memory for flag counter
flagID = shmget(flagKey, sizeof(enum state[maxProc]), IPC_CREAT |  0666);
if (flagID == -1){
    perror("Flag: Failed to designate shared memory");
    return 1;
}

flag = shmat(flagID, NULL, 0);
if (flag == (enum state*)-1){
    perror("Flag: Failed to attach shared memory");
    return 1;
}

//Initializing shared memory for the process count array
pidID = shmget(pidKey, sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT | 0666);
if (pidID == -1){
    perror("PID: Failed to designate shared memory");
    return 1;
}

pidList = shmat(pidID, NULL, 0);
if (pidList == (int*)-1){
    return 1;
}
```

EDIT: Made suggested edits. The flag comparison does not throw an error anymore (enum state*). Now I get Warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lack cast for the other three (clockVar, shmMsg, and pidList). I also added my declarations up top. I am sure I am just messing up some syntax here. Thanks!

Comment: `shmget` returns an `int` .. what type are your `*ID` variables?

Comment: I added the variables above and implemented (probably incorrectly) the suggested change by Felix. Added notes.

Answer (score 2):

`shmat()` returns a **pointer**, and you're comparing it to an integer. See the  [`shmat()` manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/2/shmat):

> On success `shmat()` returns the address of the attached shared memory segment; on error `(void *) -1` is returned

Change your code like this (assuming your variable declarations you don't show in your question have the correct types, in this case, `void *shmMsg;`):

```
// [...]
shmMsg = shmat(msgID, NULL, 0);
if (shmMsg == (void*) -1){
    //[...]
```

and you should be fine.

Comment: I edited the code above to try to implement this and it worked for the enum, but not the int pointer arrays. What am I doing wrong?